# session_start() and curl php 

Tags: php, facebook, session, curl, helper

I do not know, but whenever the `PHPSESSID` cookie is created, all my scripts that use curl are getting slow, someone could tell me why?

even without the `session_start()`. doesn't matter.

Comment: Show some code,maybe you have something else going on

Comment: should i put session_write_close() on botton of this curl page?

i read about it in google

Comment: well you can paste some more code in your question showing which part of your code seems to affect performance, maybe you might have some other stuff that are cause the problem. we can't really answer your question without really knowing what yoou are talking about

Comment: well, it's a simple code:

<?php
session_start();

curl connection

Comment: how i said, doesn't matter if i put session_start or not, if PHPSESSID cookie exists... this curl page run slow, i rly don't understand it

Comment: if i remove this cookie, it run normal

Comment: how is your curl related to your session

Answer (score 0):

What version of php are you using? because i know there have been very big performance update from php4 to php5.

Sessions write the information to a file, so there might be write issues.

if you are using your own sessions handler that can cause a slow down too. try using only php basic session methods rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have activated the php.ini setting `session.auto_start`.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

As mentioned before: How is cURL and PHP related in your question? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more info / code all I can suggest is that you call `session_write_close()` before making any cURL calls and see if that improves anything.

However, the most probable scenario is that your cURL speed is not related to the `PHPSESSID`  cookie.